# How to remove ppa:ondrej/apache2

Tags: package-management, ppa

I am on Mint 17.3 Rosa and would like to remove the following ppa:ondrej/apache2.

If I run

```
ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/apache2
```

it tells me what packages I should replace back with the originals:

```
Package revert list generated:
 automake/rosa dh-python/rosa libssl1.0.2:amd64/rosa openssl/rosa
```

But I see no obvious way how to achieve that, any help appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install automake/rosa dh-python/rosa libssl1.0.2:amd64/rosa openssl/rosa
```

should do the trick; it will prompt you to verify you really do want to downgrade.

Comment: Note that Mint 17.3 is based on Ubuntu Trusty, so I used `automake/trusty` and similarly the others with success, the only thing that remains is `libssl1.0.2:amd64` which does not appear to exist in Trusty.